# Execution on ./ not sh

Tags: bash, unix

this is part of my current code

```
#! /bin/bash

#Take no arguments in
#checks to see if home/deleted is in existence
#creates the directory or file if it is missing
**(line 15)** function checkbin(){

    if [ ! -c "~/deleted" ]; then
            mkdir -p ~/deleted
    fi
    if [ ! -f "~/.restore.info" ]; then
            touch ~/deleted/.restore.info
    fi

}
```

I can call this code properly using `./remove [ARGS]` 
however when I call using `sh remove [ARGS]`
I receive the following error `remove: 15: remove: Syntax error: "(" unexpected`

ls -l on the file `-rwxr-x--x`

Does unix support execution on both sh and ./ ?

Comment: sh will execute in Bourne shell, while you want to execute in bash.

Comment: call as `bash remove [ARGS]` or rewrite script to sh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when executing with `./` /bin/bash is used (as define in shebang) whereas `sh` may be another interpreter or a link to bash which can have a different behaviour depending on how it is called `sh`.

bash is derived from sh but has some specific syntax:

for example in sh `Function Definition Command` is

```
fname() compound-command[io-redirect ...]
```

without `function` keyword.

For more details

[Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/)

[Posix shell](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html)

Answer (score 1):

If you want your script to run in `sh` as well as in `bash`, you need to be writing to the POSIX shell standard.

In this case, that means not using the Bash `function` keyword:

```
checkbin(){
    test -c "~/deleted" || mkdir -p ~/deleted
    test -f  "~/.restore.info" || touch ~/deleted/.restore.info
}
```

If you're writing portable shell, then it's a good idea to use `#!/bin/sh` as your shebang.

(BTW, I assume you're aware that `"~/deleted"` and `~/deleted` are in no way alike?)